# Grub error after converting VM raw disk to qcow2

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am converting disks of a set of VMs run by KVM to QCOW2 format. They all are based on the same Ubuntu version 16.04

1. Stop VM: `virsh shutdown vm-name` (I wait until VM is stopped)
2. Convert disk: `qemu-img convert -f raw -O qcow2 vm-name.img vm-name.qcow2` (finishes without errors)
3. Edit VM config: `virsh edit vm-name` then change disk format to qcow2 and path to disk file to point to qcow2 disk.

After starting VM **usually** I see this error in console `error:file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.` and GRUB rescue prompt.

But for some reason after several attempts that worked for two VMs out of 6.
No luck since then. For now I am stuck and not only solutions but even ideas on where to look would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

May be hardware on virtual machine was changed. There are several methods to rescue Ubuntu boot:

[How to Repair, Restore, or Reinstall Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD or USB](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

[Grub2/Installing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)